# How to query: Select games in categories A, B and C

Tags: sql, nhibernate, hql

I'd like to know how to effectively run a query such as:

```
select game from Game game 
inner join game.Categories cat
where cat.Name in ('A', 'B')
```

This gives me games with categories **A** or **B**. But I want games that the the A category **and** the B category. This is to be used in HQL (NHibernate Query Language), but I'd like also to know how to do this on SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `MySQL`:

```
SELECT  g.*
FROM    game g
WHERE   EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    categories c
        WHERE   c.name IN ('A', 'B')
                AND c.game = g.id
        LIMIT 1 OFFSET 1
        )
```

The `OFFSET` value should be the number of items in the `IN` list minus `1`, that is if you query for `('A', 'B', 'C')` then you should use `OFFSET 2`, etc.

Comment: +1 - Nice solution.  I had never thought of doing it this way.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the SQL (assuming T-SQL):

```
/* Defining my own schema... */
declare @games table
(
 GameID int, Game varchar(20)
)

declare @gameCategories table
(
 GameID int, Category char(1)
)

insert into @games values (1, 'Risk')
insert into @games values (2, 'Spades')
insert into @games values (3, 'Cribbage')

insert into @gameCategories values (1, 'B')
insert into @gameCategories values (2, 'C')
insert into @gameCategories values (3, 'C')
insert into @gameCategories values (3, 'B')

select g.Game
from @games g
 inner join @gameCategories b on g.GameID = b.GameID and b.Category = 'B'
 inner join @gameCategories c on g.GameID = c.GameID and c.Category = 'C'
```